# Adding two numbers stored as a linked list - Unable to solve using C

Tags: c, linked-list

I understood the problem but I am not able to solve it in 'C'.

```
struct ListNode* newnode(struct ListNode* node, int data) {
    struct ListNode* temp = node;
    struct ListNode* newnode = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));    
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newnode;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->val = data;
    return newnode;
}  

struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2) {
    struct ListNode* l;
    struct ListNode* temp = l;

    int carry = 0;
    while (l1 != NULL || l2 != NULL) {
        int sum = 0;
        if (l1 != NULL) {
            sum += l1->val;
            l1 = l1->next;
        }
        if (l2 != NULL) {
            sum += l2->val;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
        if (sum >= 10) {    
            temp  = newnode(l, carry);
            carry = sum % 10;
        }
        else {
            temp = newnode(l, carry + sum);
        }
    }       
    return l;
}
```

Getting runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode' (solution.c).
I ran the function 'newnode' separately that works fine.

Need help, just a beginner.

Comment: The function newnode has undefined behavior in case when the list is initially empty.

Comment: It seems that this code snippet         if (sum >= 10) {    
            temp  = newnode(l, carry);
            carry = sum % 10;
        } does not make sense. Consider the case when the first nodes of the list has sum that is greater than 10. What will be stored in the new list?

Comment: First thing first, enable compiler warnings and treat them as errors.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yeah you are right.  
            if(sum >= 10){
                
                temp = newnode(l,sum+carry-10);
                carry = sum%10;
            
            }But this should work right??

Comment: @user10501730 These statements      struct ListNode* l;
    struct ListNode* temp = l; and this statement return l; do not make sense because the variable l is not initialized.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a [mre]. How `ListNode` is declared? Can you give us an example of input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Handle adding new node to empty lists:

```c
struct ListNode* newnode(struct ListNode* node, int data){

    struct ListNode* temp = node;
    struct ListNode *newnode = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));

    if(temp == NULL){
       newnode->val = data;
       newnode->next = NULL;
       return newnode;
    }
    while(temp->next != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newnode;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->val = data;

    return newnode;
}
```

Comment: The function does not set the data member next when temp is equal to NULL.     if(temp == NULL){
       newnode->val = data;
       return newnode;
    }